# Angular - Proxy for backend api with docker-compose

Tags: angular, docker

Is the server or the client which makes the HTTP request to the API ?

If it is the client that sends the request, then the request's response the localhost:8080/users tell me that I don't have the CORS flags enabled.

If it is serverside, then I settled up a proxy.config.json file to change api URL.
It does not work properly. I want to change localhost to backend:8080 according to the docker configuration.

Here is my proxy config:

```
{
    "*": {
        "target": "http://backend:8080",
        "secure": false
    }
}
```

I tried to make [this](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/fixing-cors-errors-with-angular-cli-proxy-e5e0ef143f85) work.

Comment: R. Richards Thanks for having changed my post. It is very rare for me to post a comment/question.. I think it is executing client side but if you can confirm, that would be great

Comment: Angular is client side, so its the client that makes the HTTP request. As per your proxy, I don't believe you can just use a wildcard for all request, otherwise your routing completely broken due to it trying to divert all calls to your server. https://angular.io/guide/build#rewrite-the-url-path

Comment: Ah!! That's what I expected! Thanks a lot for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final solution: add @CrossOrigin() to controllers on backend Spring API.

As penleychan said, it has to be configured server side